# Model connected to other models cannot load foreign keys to code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2015

The following model class(reservations) contains a customer and campingspot model which are loaded into the database as IDs. However when I try to retrieve a list of all these reservations I cannot acccess the customer or campspot information linked to the reservation.

```
public class Reservation
{


    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public UserAccount Customer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public CampingSpot CampSpot { get; set; }
```

How would I make it possible to be able to access this information, because currently it is always a null value instead of an ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you want is

```
[RequiredNotDefault]
public int UserAccountId { get; set;}

[ForeignKey("UserAccountId")]
public virtual UserAccount Customer { get; set; }
```

and the same for CampingSpot

Comment: entity framework can really turn into a pain (and be a resource hog) depending on how your domain model is laid out. glad I could help!