# Post nested model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, django, asp.net-web-api

Currently my api post works like this:

POST: localhost:55974/api/trades/

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "baseProduct": {
    "id": 1,
    "productID": "sample string 2",
    "tags": [
      "sample string 1",
      "sample string 2"
    ]
  },
  "productDescription": "sample string 2",
  "images": [
    "QEA=",
    "QEA="
  ],
  "price": 3,
  "estimatedShippingDate": "2017-03-31T20:41:03.2760924+09:00"
}
```

What I want is to link the existing data with its id; something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "baseProduct": 1,
  "productDescription": "sample string 2",
  "images": [
    "QEA=",
    "QEA="
  ],
  "price": 3,
  "estimatedShippingDate": "2017-03-31T20:41:03.2760924+09:00"
}
```

Note that `baseProduct` has changed to its ID, but when I try to do this, I get this error:

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "tradeModel.baseProduct": [
      "Error converting value 3 to type 'EodiRoad.Models.BaseProductModel'. Path 'baseProduct', line 2, position 19."
    ]
  }
}
```

This worked fine in django so I guess that it will have its way on ASP.NET too. 
 Any possible solutions?

=== EDIT ====
my data model looks like this.

Trademodel.cs

```
public class TradeModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("baseProduct")]
        public int baseProductId { get; set; }

        public virtual BaseProductModel baseProduct { get; set; }

        // public BaseProductModel baseProduct { get; set; }

        public string productDescription { get; set; }
        public List<byte[]> images { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
        // Date infos
        public DateTime estimatedShippingDate { get; set; }

    }
```

BaseProductModel.cs

```
public class BaseProductModel
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string productID { get; set; }
    // Not in use
    public List<string> tags { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: assuming you're using entity framework in the background, the solution here should work  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936875/model-connected-to-other-models-cannot-load-foreign-keys-to-code/42936929#42936929

Comment: thanks!! that would work. but i have no idea about implementing this..[RequiredNotDefault]

Comment: that's not critical to it, just having the id as a field and the object as a virtual works. actually looking at it the required not default is a custom data annotation we use here, [Required] would be fine. we use that to assure an int isn't 0, a string isn't blank, a guid isn't all 0s, etc

Comment: asp.net still requires me to enter both baseProductId and the form of baseProduct. + get request gives me an error..

Comment: can you put up the class definitions?

Comment: i've edited my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139584/discussion-between-eric-lizotte-and-uzu).

Comment: what i was looking for was DTOs. different types for get/post